# Does latest actionlib_java for electric exist?

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
Has any body latest actionlib_java for electric version used? It seems that actionlib_java has been removed. What is the latest actionlib to support action server/client in java? What happens to those java application which use actionlib_java?

thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39639/does-latest-actionlib_java-for-electric-exist?/) by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2012-07-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See http://answers.ros.org/question/37198/rosjava-actionlib/

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on 2012-07-26**:
Hi damonkohle, yes I saw it before. But we have applications which we already made and they need actionlib_java. Do we need to alter  code and change everything that dependent on actionlib_java? my pckg uses actionlib_java,I give it to someone, how does he get actionlib_java to compile that pckg?

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-07-27**:
Currently your only option is to implement your own actionlib or revert to an older version of rosjava that supports it.

**Comment by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on 2012-08-14**:
Hi damonkhole, Does new and latest rosjava support actionserver/client implementation. How can I make new actionserver/cleint applications based on rosjava? Thanks